# How do I get separate plots for each dosegroup in SAS?

Tags: plot, sas

The problem is, I am comparing the effectiveness of two dosing levels of a drug against a placebo. The placebo is the control group, and I have a low dose group  and a high dose group. I am trying to get separate histograms and normal quantile plots for each separate group. I am not getting any errors, but I am also not finding anything helpful from SAS itself. Does anyone know?

Here is my code:

```
Data Memory;
input dosegrp $ funct @@; datalines;
Pla 6 Pla 5 Pla 6 Pla 8 Pla 3 Pla 4 Pla 7 Pla 4 Pla 7 Pla 6 Pla 7 Pla 8 Pla 5 Pla 6 Pla 5 Pla 5 Pla 7 Pla 8 Pla 5 Pla 9 Pla 11 Pla 4 Pla 7
lo 8 lo 12 lo 7 lo 8 lo 5 lo 6 lo 6 lo 5 lo 3 lo 6 lo 9 lo 6 lo 11 lo 8 lo 6 lo 9 lo 11 lo 5
hi 11 hi 7 hi 7 hi 11 hi 9 hi 9 hi 12 hi 13 hi 9 hi 13 hi 10 hi 12 hi 9 hi 15 hi 12 hi 14 hi 15 hi 12
;
proc sort data = Memory; by dosegrp;
proc means mean std n data = Memory;
by dosegrp;
var funct;
title1 'one-way ANOVA';
title2 'Homework 8 Memory function';
RUN;
title 'Tests for normality';
proc univariate normal data = Memory;
by dosegrp;
var funct;
run;
ods graphics on;
proc glm data = Memory plots=all;
class dosegrp;
model funct=dosegrp; means dosegrp/hovtest welch t dunnett('Pla');
contrast 'active vs placebo' dosegrp 0.5 0.5 -1;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is how to get histograms and quantile plots for separate groups for a variable.

If that's the case then you do have the correct proc and can use `PROC UNIVARIATE` and the `histogram` and `qqplot` statements.

```
title 'Tests for normality';

proc univariate normal data=Memory;
    by dosegrp;
    histogram funct;
    qqplot funct;
run;
```

There are more usage examples in the SAS documentation in the examples (e.g. see 4.28):
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/66703/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_syntax30.htm

Comment: Reeza, that seems to have worked. Just real quick, if I want stem and leaf plots, I need to specify `ods graphics off`, right?

Comment: Yes, those are generated using the printer plot, similar to a dot matrix print out.